# VB Stored Reference Lists

Tags: vb.net

I've successfully developed a good portion of a project i'm working on. To add greater functionality and ease coding I'd like to have a "reference list" of properties to bridge the gap between the UI and code. A lot of the code will end up looking like:

object.property(SuperLongStringWhichActsAs.Integer.AndIsUnusableInUI)

or

object.property(integer)

So the integer relating to the "width" property might be 1, with a possible substitute value of "bunchoftext.efields.width", and I'd like to show it in the UI as "Width". If the user selects "Width" in the UI, I'd like the returned value to be "1" for use in code, as "object.property(Width)" will not work, but "object.property(1)" will.

Is there any way to store a list of strings and their related values to be referenced by the program?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Sounds like you need a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx). Declare yours as a `Dictionary(Of String, Integer)`.

Comment: That worked! Thanks Vincent.